# 負荷の高いプロセスを、自動で定間隔でチェックする方法

Tags: linux, rhel

負荷の高いプロセスを、自動で定間隔でチェックする方法を教えてください。

夜間や土日祝日の、どの時間帯に負荷がかかっているかを調査したいと思っています。

シェルを作ってスケジューラで定間隔で起動させる・・・のような、なんとなくのイメージはあるのですが、
Linuxは初心者のため、妥当な方法がわかりません。

なるべくサーバに負荷のかからない良い方法があれば教えてください。

環境は、Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.3 です。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://okwave.jp/qa/q9397425.html

Answer (score 2):

`cron`を利用するなら`/etc/crontab`に`32 * * * * root /bin/ps -A -O pcpu --sort -pcpu | head >/path/to/log/dir/pslog-$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)`という感じで登録するのはどうでしょうか？
全てのプロセスをcpu使用率の降順でソートして上から10個をログに残します。

ログに残す情報を変更したい場合は`man ps`をして`OUTPUT MODIFIERS`セクションを参照してください。